# How to use descendants

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I have something like:

```
doc.css('results[name="test"]').map { |node| file.write node.ancestors("tests").first['name']; file.write "\n" }
```

But what I want to write is:

```
doc.css('tests').map{ |node| file.write node.first['name'] if node.descendants('results').first['name'] == "test" }
```

But there is no method `descendants`.
If I want go with the second approach what should I modify in the snippet?

Comment: Is it possible to add a sample test file where upon this script needs to be run?

Comment: The real file contains confidential data, I have changed the contend above before posting it here.

Comment: Please read "[mcve]". When asking about a problem with your code please include the minimum input data that demonstrates the problem you're having. Without that we have to try to create something that matches the code which wastes time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
doc.css('tests').each { |node| file.write node['name'] if node.css('results[name="test"]').any? }
```

or

```
doc.css('tests').select { |node| node.css('results[name="test"]').any? }.each { |node| file.write node['name'] }
```

Comment: You are back again :).  Somehow the second code is faster than the first one. I don't understand why. Anyway that was the reason I wanted to check it. Atleast 10x faster.